# In unpacking do you find the ECX value or the ESP value for Aspack 2.12?

Tags: malware

I am teaching myself how to do malware analysis. While attempting to analyze a malicious file found on a USB drive it came to my attention that this malware was packed with Aspacker 2.12 (PEiD). I've never come across Aspack before, and a quick google search led me to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3QeEqC4-jE 
This guys says to find the ECX register to find the Original Entry Point.

another google search led me to another tutorial on a site calls tuts4you (I can't post the link because you need to download the file to view the tutorial) but THIS guy says to find the ESP register and the EDI register and do exactly the same thing.

They both use ollydbg and import REC, and it appears that the tutorials are showing the exact same thing - namely finding the OEP for unpacking ASpack.

Since I am new to this, would someone mind explaining which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 3):

Hope the question is not too obsolete...
There are more ways to achieve this task. You can follow steps in the mentioned tutorial or try other ways (usually dependent on packers version/options, etc). To mention one alternative approach, try to find following instructions in you packed executable:

```
6800000000   push 0
C3           retn
```

Set the breakpoint to this `push 0` instruction and run executable. This instruction will be modified during packers code exection and `0` (DWORD 0x000000) will be replaced with address (DWORD) of the original entry point (so the instruction will look like `push 00451000` for example).

Once executed, address of OEP will be pushed to the stack and following `ret` instruction will take it as return address where the execution should continue....thus setting `EIP` (instruction pointer) to original entrypoint.

For search for these instructions, I recommend some hex editor or HIEW32...search for following hex pattern:
`6800000000C3`